# Detecting network adapter status change C#

Tags: c#, windows-services, network-programming

I want to monitor all network adapter and their states using C#. 
For example when a network adapter goes up or down i need to capture that along with adapter information such as name. mac, ip.
I have used `NetworkChange.NetworkAvailabilityChanged` but this gives only network status not the adapter which has got connected/disconnected.

My application is windows service application and i don't want use WMI.

Comment: What is the sender argument to the event handler? Can you not extract the information you need from that by casting it to the appropriate type?

Comment: I have tried that also. As per MSDN the sender is source for that event but i am getting that as null.

Comment: It seems like you will have to implement some kind of polling logic: periodically check adapters status and detect changes by yourself.